# Accepting a callback to a function as param

Tags: ios, swift, snapkit

I am using SnapKit and I am trying to pass the closure as a param to my function which calls snp_makeConstaints like below,

```
func drawView(view: UIView, callback: (() -> Void)!) {
    self.addSubview(view)
    view.snp_makeConstraints(closure: callback)
}
```

I am getting the following error,

`../example.swift:57:43: Cannot convert value of type '(() -> Void)!' to expected argument type '@noescape (make: ConstraintMaker) -> Void'`

Therefore I added `(make: ConstaintMaker) -> Void`

which resulted in the following error, 
`Use of undeclared type 'ConstraintMaker'`

I do not understand what `@noescape` is and why it is saying that `ConstraintMaker` is undeclared.

Comment: Because snp_makeConstraints expects (make: ConstraintMaker) -> Void and you are trying to pass () -> Void?

Comment: @sliwinski.lukas When I add (make: ConstraintMaker) it shows the following error, `Use of undeclared type 'ConstraintMaker'`

Comment: You have to import some module. Check for SnapKit documentation which one.

Comment: I have included the module, I am also able to use it directly but not able to pass as callback to my method.

Comment: @sliwinski.lukas My bad, I had included the module in the main file but not in the file I was writing the function in.

Answer (score 0):

Add `import SnapKit` on the top of the swift file where you have the problem.